# Equivalence of expected value formulae

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

The expected value $E$ of a function $f(x)$ can be computed by two ways:

$E[f(x)] = \int f(x) \cdot p(x) dx$

and

$ E[f(x)] = \int f(x) \, dP(x)$

Where:

$p(x)$ = Probability density function

$P(x)$ = Cumulative probability function

I would like to prove both are equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $p(x)$ exists, it is related to $P(x)$ as - $$\frac{\mathrm dP(x)} {\mathrm dx} = p(x) $$
Hence $$\begin{align}E[f(x)] &= \int f(x)~\mathrm dP(x)\\[1ex]&=\int f(x)~\frac{\mathrm dP(x)} {\mathrm dx} ~\mathrm dx\\[1ex]& = \int f(x)~p(x)~\mathrm  dx\end{align}$$